# Failed approximate-ndt-mapping with odom topic

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We sometimes succeeded and sometimes failed to do approximate-ndt-mapping provided with Autoware (v1.13), which depends on the shape of the course we wanted to map out and etc.
Instead of mapping only with the lidar topic (/points_raw), we tried to add the odom topic (/vehicle/odom) to it so we're expecting we could make it more often.
However, we didn't make it as shown in this video - https://youtu.be/491T8yIHqP4.
I'm wondering what I was wrong.
Any piece of advice will be appreciated.
Thank you :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354516/failed-approximate-ndt-mapping-with-odom-topic/) by [wsung1](https://answers.ros.org/users/48426/wsung1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2020-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@wsung1 Please make sure you are setting `use_odom` to `true` in the `ndt_matching.launch` file and you have something publishing your odometry on the topic `/vehicle/odom` as a `sensor_msgs/Odometry` message. If you need to convert `sensor_msgs/TwistStamped` to an (incomplete) `sensor_msgs/Odometry`, there is a utility package called `twist2odom` for this purpose.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2020-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2020-06-13**:
@wsung1 this was a typo. Should be `nav_msgs/Odometry`.

**Comment by [wsung1](https://answers.ros.org/users/48426/wsung1/) on 2020-06-13**:
Thanks for your reply, @Josh Whitley. As can be seen in the video, the odom topic /vehicle/odom has a rosmsg type of nav_msgs/Odometry. Should it be sensor_msgs/Odometry? I couldn't find a rosmsg by that name, though.

**Comment by [wsung1](https://answers.ros.org/users/48426/wsung1/) on 2020-06-13**:
@Josh Whitley, I'm wondering why small submap files (hundreds kB) are spawned when starting approximate-ndt-mapping with setting use_odom to true. Do you have any idea about that?

**Comment by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) on 2020-06-16**:
This is a separate question and should be started in a new Question on ROS Answers. Were you able to get NDT to accept the `/vehicle/odom` topic?